# Notification email sending using pam with shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell, authentication, unix, pam

I try to run an external script with pam.exec_so, that pulls the variables and sends notification emails. It is working, but the only problem I have with it, if I log in through a domain my $PAM_USER variable becomes "DOMAIN\username" so if I try to use it as a string I get sent a mail and this part becomes "DOMAIN  sername" without the middle part sadly.

I tried using sed to change all single backslash to double but shell already interpreted the variable or something. Printf did not work either.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I suspect the problem is not how you print the variable, but how it is assigned. Could you please add this to your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.